# Google analytics v4 timing для android

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

Для трекинга времени в GA v4 for android, родной мануал рекомендует использовать

```
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.TimingBuilder()
            .setCategory(category)
            .setValue(value)
            .setVariable(variable)
            .setLabel(label)
            .build());
```

Не получается найти в интерфейсе GA отображение тайминга в реальном времени.
Есть сводка в разделе "поведение", но эта статистика обновляется раз в сутки, как я понял? Каким образом можно грамотно сделать тайминг и видеть его сразу? 
Есть соблазн впихнуть его в events, но понимаю, что это неверно.
Также, когда передается

```
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(category)
            .setAction(action)
            .setLabel(label)
            .setValue(value)
            .build());
```

Где в интерфейсе можно найти значение value?

Также, буду благодарен за ссылки на примеры грамотного кода по использованию GA v4 для android.

И еще, насколько совместимы в использовании GA v4 и appodeal? Кто использовал такую связку, прошу прокомментировать.